# Tokyo Cabinet Tuning Parameters

Tags: configuration, parameters, performance, tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

I have been trying to find a better Tokyo Cabinet (or Tokyo Tyrant) configuration for my application, but I don't know exactly how. I know what some parameters mean but I want to have a fine tuning control, so I need to know the impact of each one. The Tokyo documentation is really good but not at this point.

- `TCHDB -> *bool tchdbtune(TCHDB *hdb, int64_t bnum, int8_t apow, int8_t fpow, uint8_t opts);*`

How do I use: `bnum`, `apow` and `fpow`?

- `TCBDB -> *bool tcbdbtune(TCBDB *bdb, int32_t lmemb, int32_t nmemb, int64_t bnum, int8_t apow, int8_t fpow, uint8_t opts);*`

How do I use: `lmemb`, `nmemb`, `bnum`, `apow` and `fpow`?

- `TCFDB -> *bool tcfdbtune(TCFDB *fdb, int32_t width, int64_t limsiz);*`

How do I use: `width` and `limsiz`? Note: I am only putting this to get all types of database in the topic, this one is really simple.

- `TCTDB -> *bool tctdbtune(TCTDB *tdb, int64_t bnum, int8_t apow, int8_t fpow, uint8_t opts);*`

How do I use: `bnum`, `apow` and `fpow`?

Answer (score 2):

I stood before the same problem.

But because the results will highly depend on your application, my advise as a [two factrial experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment):

- Benchmark your application with a low value and a high value for each parameter (use multiple runs to gain confidence into the results)
- Calculate based on the benchmark results (the effect of each factor)

You have than data that indicates the importance of the parameters. Factors with a high effect are very significant for the performance, factors with a low effect are not important.

You should than fine tune the important parameters.